# if self.request.GET[key] fetch value of key?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get the value of a key in the URL (localhost:8080?color=red) and display different pages according to what value is in the url (*red* or *blue*...etc). I'm not sure how to set that up, though, because nothing I've tried works. Any ideas? It's for a class assignment, so I can't use query_string.

```
    if self.request.GET(['color','red']):
        view = ContentPage()
        fetch_data = Data()
        name = fetch_data.red.name
        description = fetch_data.red.description
        self.response.write(view.print_first() + name + description + view.print_end())
    else:
        see = Page()
        self.response.write(see.output())
```

Comment: if self.request.GET['color'] == 'red':  ..... or self.request.get('color', default_value='') == 'red': .....

Answer (score 0):

Use self.request.get, like this:

```
color = self.request.get('color')
# do something with color
```